# Genymotion Stuck at boot screen

Tags: android, genymotion

I am on Mac OSX Catalina. Genymotion was running perfectly fine. However, suddenly it is getting stuck on splash screen/boot screen and stays there forever. I am using the latest version of Virtualbox (6.0.18).

Steps I have taken so far:
1. Reinstalling both (Genymotion and Virtualbox)
2. Deleting the .Genymobile folder

Which didn't fix the issue

My specs:
MacBook Pro Retina late 2013
16gb Ram
i7 4850HQ

These are the logs:
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmB2c.png)
Thanks

Comment: go to system settings and allow for emulator permission

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you are using Genymotion?

If not then I'd suggest looking into [Android Studio emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator). It is well-supported by Google and it's a recommended solution for Android development and testing^

Comment: Also, if looking something for gaming, you can use BlueStacks. Much easier, no need to suffer from all that dance with Playmarket installation in Genymotion.